# Категория Wordpress ведет на 404-ю страницу

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Создаю custom post type в wordpress и категории для него:

```
// Register Custom Post Type - Events
function events_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => __( 'Події', 'Post Type General Name', '{domain}' ),
        'singular_name'         => __( 'Події', 'Post Type Singular Name', '{domain}' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Події', '{domain}' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Події', '{domain}' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Архив подій', '{domain}' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Характеристики подій', '{domain}' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Item:', '{domain}' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'Усі подій', '{domain}' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Додати нову подію', '{domain}' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Додати подію', '{domain}' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'Нова подія', '{domain}' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Редагувати подію', '{domain}' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Оновити подію', '{domain}' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'Переглянути подію', '{domain}' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'Переглянути події', '{domain}' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Пошук події', '{domain}' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Подія не найдена', '{domain}' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', '{domain}' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Зображення події', '{domain}' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Встановити зображення події', '{domain}' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Видалити зображення', '{domain}' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Встановити як ображення події', '{domain}' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', '{domain}' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', '{domain}' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', '{domain}' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', '{domain}' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', '{domain}' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Події', '{domain}' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Сторінки з подіями.', '{domain}' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'excerpt'),
        'taxonomies'            => array('event'),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 6,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'event', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'events_post_type', 0 );
// Register Custom Post Type - Events

// Register Custom Category Type - Events
function create_event_categories() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category Name' ),
        'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, // Set this to 'false' for non-hierarchical taxonomy (like tags)
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'event' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'event', array( 'event' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_event_categories', 0 );
// Register Custom Category Type - Events
```

Однако при наполнении вижу что и пустые категории и заполненные ведут на 404-ю страницу.

> Отакої! Цю сторінку не знайдено.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Надо пересохранить постоянные ссылки.

Comment: Пробовал - не помогает. Все равно 404

Comment: Откройте документацию и прочитайте то, что написано на красном фоне и бросается в глаза сразу: https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_taxonomy

Comment: Да, спасибо. Увидел.